# error: constructor delegates to itself problem

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include "RandomGeneratorNAG.h"
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG():RandomGeneratorNAG()  {
}

/** Standard constructor.
 * \param seed Seed for the randomGenerator
 */
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG(int seed) {
    g05cbc(seed);
}

/** Standard destructor.
 *
 */
RandomGeneratorNAG::~RandomGeneratorNAG() {
}
```

I have the error message "error: constructor delegates to itself" in this point. What is the problem??

After I change the first function to

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG(){
}
```

I have the error message

> "error: no matching function for call to
>   'RandomGenerator::RandomGenerator()'"

in this point again.

RandomGeneratorNAG.h looks like the following.

```
#ifndef RANDOMGENERATOR_RANDOMGENERATORNAG_H_
#define RANDOMGENERATOR_RANDOMGENERATORNAG_H_

#include "RandomGenerator.h"


/// To use this class, you must have WITH_NAG enabled in CMake.
class RandomGeneratorNAG: public RandomGenerator {
public:
    RandomGeneratorNAG();
        explicit RandomGeneratorNAG(int seed);
    virtual ~RandomGeneratorNAG();

    void getUniformRandomInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound, int* randNumber) ;
    void getUniformRandomInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound, std::vector<int>* randNumbers, std::size_t  size) ;
    void getUniformRandomDouble(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double* randNumber) ;
    void getUniformRandomDouble(double lowerBound, double upperBound, std::vector<double>* randNumbers, std::size_t  size) ;

    void getNormalRandomInt(double mu, double sigma, int* randNumber) ;
    void getNormalRandomInt(double mu, double sigma, std::vector<int>* randNumbers, std::size_t  size) ;
    void getNormalRandomDouble(double mu, double sigma, double* randNumber) ;
    void getNormalRandomDouble(double mu, double sigma, std::vector<double>* randNumbers, std::size_t  size) ;
};

#endif /* RANDOMGENERATOR_RANDOMGENERATORNAG_H_ */
```

Also, RandomGenerator.h is like following.

```
#ifndef _RandomGenerator_hpp_
#define _RandomGenerator_hpp_

#include <vector>
#if BUILD_TESTS
//Necessary include to test private functions with googleTest
#include "gtest/gtest_prod.h"
#endif

#include "../Parameter/Parameter.h"
#include "../Writer/Writer.h"

class RandomGenerator {
#if BUILD_TESTS
    FRIEND_TEST(RandomGeneratorTest, seed);
#endif
protected:
    int seed;
    static int createSeed();
public:

    virtual ~RandomGenerator();

    RandomGenerator(int seed);

    int getSeed(){return seed;}

    static RandomGenerator* factory(Parameter* parameter, Writer* writer);

    virtual void getUniformRandomInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound, int* randNumber) = 0;

    virtual void getUniformRandomInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound, std::vector<int> *randNumbers, std::size_t size) = 0;

    virtual void getUniformRandomDouble(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double* randNumber) = 0;

    virtual void getUniformRandomDouble(double lowerBound, double upperBound, std::vector<double> *randNumbers,
                                        std::size_t size) = 0;

    virtual void getNormalRandomInt(double mu, double sigma, int* randNumber) = 0;

    virtual void getNormalRandomInt(double mu, double sigma, std::vector<int> *randNumbers, std::size_t size) = 0;

    virtual void getNormalRandomDouble(double mu, double sigma, double* randNumber) = 0;

    virtual void getNormalRandomDouble(double mu, double sigma, std::vector<double> *randNumbers, std::size_t size) = 0;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Your last edits are not good. They make the answers appear non-sensical.

Comment: @R Sahu, So sorry...but the problem remains....so I edited it...

Comment: your error message doesn't match the post (its missing the `NAG` part), is this error in the posted code, or is there another class, `RandomGenerator`, that has this problem?

Comment: @kmdreko, I added RandomGenerator.h code..which assumes to have problems in it..Or shall I redo the questions again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG():RandomGeneratorNAG()
{
}
```

is wrong. The `:RandomGeneratorNAG()` bit is not right. That syntax is used to call another constructor. In your case, it is the same constructor you are delegating to. It will result in an infinite loop. Perhaps it was a typo. Remove that part from your code and use:

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG()
{
}
```

If you want to use the other constructor with a seed value of `0`, use:

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG() : RandomGeneratorNAG(0)
{
}
```

You can read more about delegating constructors at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor and http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor.

#### Update, in response to OP's comment

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG()
{
}
```

is equivalent to

```
// The default constructor of the base class is called.
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG() : RandomGenerator() 
{
}
```

Since the base class does not have a default constructor, the compiler reports an error in that line.

You can resolve the issue by:

1. Adding a default constructor to the base class, or
2. Removing the default constructor in the derived class, or
3. Changing the implementation of the default constructor of the derived class.

   ```
   RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG() : RandomGenerator(0) 
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for leaving me answer...However after that I have "error: no matching function for call to 'RandomGenerator::RandomGenerator()'" How Can I interpret this?

Comment: @HannahLee, that's probably because your class does not declare a default constructor.

Comment: @R Sahu, please specify what you meant for C++ beginner??I changed to RandomGenerator(int see){}, but error still appears..

Answer (score 0):

You default constructor calls itself in the member initialization list, which would result in an infinite loop (given that the compiler allows it, which is apparently not the case):

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG() : RandomGeneratorNAG() {}
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^ Doesn't work
```

If your default ctor doesn't have to perform any initialization at all, just fix this by removing the initialization

```
RandomGeneratorNAG::RandomGeneratorNAG() {}
```